# Improving a UDF's Volatility

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have a tiny *UDF()* that returns a hyperlink's `Address`:

```
Public Function hyperAdd(r As Range) As String
    Application.Volatile

    hyperAdd = "no hyperlink"
    If r.Hyperlinks.Count = 0 Then Exit Function
    hyperAdd = r.Hyperlinks(1).Address
End Function
```

So if I put:

```
http://www.cnn.com
```

in cell **A1**, I get:

[image]

Now if I select **A1**, click in the Formula Bar, and change *cnn* to *fox*, **B1** does not change!

I have to re-Select **A1**, touch <kbd>F2</kbd> and then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
How do I fix this ??

*(if it matters, I am using Excel 2007 on a Win 7 machine)*

Comment: Wierd, even with calcs on automatic I still need to hit F9 for it to calculate.   I am stumped.

Comment: @ScottCraner What version of Excel are you using ??

Comment: I am using 2013

Comment: @ScottCraner At least I know its not just me.

Comment: @ScottCraner Also the same issue in Excel 2016 (Office 365).  It seems the Hyperlinks collection has not been updated at the time the function runs.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Thanks....Later I will experiment with re-coding the *UDF()* to receive a `Hyperlink` Object rather than a `Range` Object....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround would be to force a calculation using a worksheet change event.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then Application.CalculateFull
End Sub
```

And, of course, you can remove the `Application.Volatile` from the UDF.

The UDF seems to be triggered by the change in A1, which is expected since A1 is referenced in the argument.  But at the time it runs, the Hyperlinks collection has not yet been updated.  And, if you have a break point, you can observe that the cursor is still in the formula bar.  Perhaps it has to do with the way hyperlinks are stored and referenced.